# In JavaScript/jQuery, is it possible to track the viewability of multiple HTML elements on a page while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am working on a project where I am tracking whether or not certain elements on a page are currently within view. Thus far, I have:

```
// wait til code loads so it can grab DOM elements
$(window).load(function () {  
  // scrolling...
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    // do this if any of the element is within view; otherwise, it is invisible
    if ( ($('div').offset().top < ( $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() )) && ( ($('div').offset().top + $('div').height()) > $(window).scrollTop() ) ) {
      console.log( $('div').attr('class') + " visible");
    } else {
      console.log( $('div').attr('class') + " invisible");
    }
  });
});
```

This accurately tracks one element, being the first `div` that loads onto the page. The trick has been to gather an array using something like `var element = document.querySelectorAll('div');`. However my implementation of that has remained unsuccessful:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var elems, i;
    // select all div elements
    elems = document.querySelectorAll("div");
    // iterate through array
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
            if ( ($(elems[i]).offset().top < ( $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() )) && ( ($(elems[i]).offset().top + $(elems[i]).height()) \
> $(window).scrollTop() ) ) {
                console.log( $(elems[i].html()) + " visible");
            } else {
                console.log( $(elems[i]).html() + " invisible");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Let's assume that there are 5 div's on the page. Would it be possible to simultaneously track the viewability of each of those div's (or whatever we choose to select with `document.querySelectorAll("...")`?

I'd appreciate the help, and I hope that many people get to give this code a shot since it is pretty fun to work with!

Comment: On a general note, you don't `querySelectorAll()` when you have jQuery, that defies the purpose. You also don't typically iterate through an array of elements with a for loop, you'd use jQuery's `.each()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there already is a plugin that does that (and I urge you to go looking for one), but for the sake of the explanation:

```
$.expr[':'].inview = function(a, i, m) {
    var $win = $(window),
        $elem = $(a),
        viewportTop = $win.scrollTop(),
        viewportBottom = viewportTop + $win.height(),
        elemTop = $elem.offset().top,
        elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return (elemTop >= viewportTop && elemTop < viewportBottom) ||
           (elemBottom > viewportTop && elemBottom <= viewportBottom);
};
```

Now you can do:

```
$(function () {  
    $(window).scroll(function () {
       $("div:inview").whatever();
    });
});
```

or

```
$(function () {  
    $(window).scroll(function () {
       $("div:not(:inview)").whatever();
    });
});
```

Comment: How does this allow for tracking of multiple (maybe up to 50...) elements, which would be necessary if more than one element were visible on the page at once?

Comment: This is a selector. Its purpose is to select elements that are inside the browser's viewport. There is no upper limit to the number of elements it can select at once. I'm not sure what you mean by "tracking", though.

Comment: I'd highly recommend Waypoints.js to trigger a function on scrolling to an element: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/